# How to webscrape wiki tables of multiple Companies

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to webscrape wiki tables of multiple companies like samsung,alibaba etc,but can't able to so. Below is My code

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

csvFile = open('Information.csv', 'wt+')
writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
lst=['Samsung','Facebook','Google','Tata_Consultancy_Services','Wipro','IBM','Alibaba_Group','Baidu','Yahoo!','Oracle_Corporation']
for a in lst:
    html = urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/a")
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    table = bs.findAll('table')
    for tr in table:
        rows = tr.findAll('tr')
        for row in rows:
            csvRow = [] 
            for cell in row.findAll(['td', 'th']):
                csvRow.append(cell.get_text())

         print(csvRow)
         writer.writerow(csvRow)
```

Comment: What is your *specific* question?

Comment: Just a little tip. Probably you should be using the wikipedia API instead of just hitting their website. https://en.wikipedia.org/w/api.php

Answer (score 1):

You are passing `a` as a string itself, not a reference to one of the items in the list. Here is the corrected code:

```
import csv
from urllib.request import urlopen
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

csvFile = open('Information.csv', 'wt+')
writer = csv.writer(csvFile)
lst=['Samsung','Facebook','Google','Tata_Consultancy_Services','Wipro','IBM','Alibaba_Group','Baidu','Yahoo!','Oracle_Corporation']
for a in lst:
    html = urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{}".format(a))
    bs = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    table = bs.findAll('table')
    for tr in table:
        rows = tr.findAll('tr')
        for row in rows:
            csvRow = [] 
            for cell in row.findAll(['td', 'th']):
                csvRow.append(cell.get_text())

         print(csvRow)
         writer.writerow(csvRow)
```

Answer (score 0):

`html = urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/a")` is where the problem is.

you're looping through `lst` to get the url for each company but failed to do so by using a string literal in the `urlopen` method.

the way to solve this is to replace `html = urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/a")` with either one of the following:

- `html = urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/" + a)`
- `html = urlopen(f"https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{a}") #requires python 3.6+`
- `html = urlopen("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/{}".format(a))`